# Encriptacion de algoritmo SHA1 con Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, encriptación

Hola estoy haciendo un ejercicio de algoritmo SHA-1 con Python 3.4 y Tkinter

Mi problema es que no se cómo mostrar el resultado de la conversión de mi `caja1` a la `caja2`. Aquí les dejo el código:

```
 from tkinter import *
 from hashlib import sha1


 def encriptar():
     sha1(texto).hexdigest()


 ventana = Tk()
 ventana.geometry("600x320")

 texto = StringVar()
 texto_encriptado = StringVar()


 caja1 = Entry(ventana, textvariable=texto).place(x=150, y=50)


 botonEncriptar = Button(ventana, text="Encriptar", command=encriptar).place(x=150, y=100)

 caja2 = Entry(ventana, textvariable=texto_encriptado, width=40).place(x=150, y=200)

 ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola @Andres. Por favor realiza alguna investigación al respecto. No se permiten preguntas solicitando librerías para realizar alguna tarea. Por favor busca algo respecto a encriptación primero, o busca [python sha1] en tu buscador en línea, intenta realizar algo y si estás detenido o atascado pues publica una pregunta sobre ello. Además, ten en cuenta que django es un framework para crear aplicaciones web, mientras que la encriptación de datos no depende de un framework de desarrollo web sino del lenguaje de programación.

Comment: ya cambie mi pregunta

Comment: He reabierto la pregunta. Muchas gracias por la edición, ha quedado mejor.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza también le recomendé Andrés hace ya varios días, que cierre sus preguntas ya que tiene varias que han sido resueltas pero se mantienen como abiertas.

Comment: Edite las etiquetas ya que no está relacionado con Django

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que tienes que pasarle una cadena de texto a la función `sha1` sin embargo le estás pasando una instancia de `Tkinter.StringVar`, lo que necesitas es obtener el texto y luego setear el texto de la `caja2`.

Tu función quedaría así:

```
def encriptar():
    encriptado = sha1(texto.get()).hexdigest()
    texto_encriptado.set(encriptado)
```

Ya que estás trabajando con Python 3.x, es necesario que uses un `encode` antes de encriptar:

```
def encriptar():
    encriptado = sha1(texto.get().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    texto_encriptado.set(encriptado)
```

Y el restultado sería algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias @César

Comment: @AndresVilca de nada, si te sirvió no olvides marcarla como aceptada usando el check al costado izquierdo de mi respuesta.

Comment: Hola @AndresVilca si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.